# c# 4.0 and async with Microsoft.Bcl.Async. I don't have all the type for async modifiy

Tags: c#-4.0, async-await

I am using VS2012 and my project is 4.0, but I want to use the async/await keywords, so I install Microsoft.Bcl.Async.

I try to implement my async method in the following way:

```
public async Task<bool> myMethodAync(int paramInteger)
{
    //my code, a simple code that return a bool. Is only an example
    if(paramInteger == 2)
    {
         return true;
    }
    else return false;

}
```

I get an error and I get marked the name of the method and the error says something like this: it is not find all the types needed for the modify async. is it the target of the project a wrong version or is it missing the reference for some assembly?

I have the reference for the three assemblies Microsoft.Threading.Task, Microsoft.Threading.Task.Extensions and Microsoft.Threading.Task.Extensions.Desktop and I have the using in my class, System.Threading.task.

What else I need to do?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From  http://michaelmairegger.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/cannot-find-all-types-required-by-the-async-modifier/:

*The solution to this problem is to reference following nuGet package into all projects in which you want to use the ‘async’ and ‘await’ keyword.*

**`Microsoft.CompilerServices.AsyncTargetingPack`**

So, right click on `References`, then select `Manage NuGet Packages...`, then search online. You may find the package under the name **Async Targeting Pack for Visual Studio 11**. Install it and the problem should be solved.

Comment: what I do is install the Microsoft.Bcl.Asyn in my solution (I have many project) and when I try to install the package for the project with the problem, it says that is already installed. So is this reason why I add the reference manually, how I told in my post.